# How to Fix Stalling Xcode 10 iOS 12 Simulators?

Tags: xcode, freeze, xcode10, ios12

No matter what I do, any Xcode 10 iOS simulator that runs iOS 12 never gets past the indeterminate progress at boot up.

Other simulators running iOS 11 or earlier work fine.

How to fix this? Complete reinstall does not work...

[image]

Issue occurs for any iPhone which requires iOS 12 and any iOS device configured to run iOS 12 under the simulator.

Comment: Whatever is broken also causes the Swift Playgrounds to stall and installd starts eating processor.

Comment: I lost days of productivity on this. Xcode is only free if your time is worth nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately **it took a complete removal of Xcode** and then the basic re-download and run of Xcode which then re-distributes *stuff* all over your hard disk again.

First I **backed up my customizations** found in the folders and files:

1. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`
2. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes`
3. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings`
4. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates`
5. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
6. `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Then I **removed the following** (although my Xcode is not in `/Applications`, I list it that way here):

1. `/Applications/Xcode.app`
2. `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
3. `~/Library/Developer ~/Library/MobileDevice`
4. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
5. `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
6. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.bom`
7. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.plist`
8. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.bom`
9. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.plist`

and then **re-download Xcode from the App Store**:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

And then **re-insert my customizations**.  When the folder where customizations were stored did not exist, I went into Xcode and created a temp customization (like code a code snippet) and let Xcode create the containing folder to be safe. Then I deleted the temp customization and re-populated the new Xcode created folder with my customizations again.

**For the first time since iOS 12 was in beta, I was able to successfully download and install it.**

*And by the way, the iOS 12 simulator disk image (if you want to install it via the standard macOS Installer app instead) is here:*

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_0-12.0.1.1537588161.dmg

Comment: It would be nice if Apple just produced the simulators like Xcode plugins with separate store links. It was so easy with the simulator disk image when I ran the *normal* Installer.app to install the simulator.  The Xcode Preferences -> Components -> Simulators is just more bad monolithic design that complicates matters. Why not just a folder of simulators like Frameworks work. Download and drag it to the right place. Manage it in the Finder. Sheesh